# Slideshow Feature not available in Gallery after ICS Update

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, gallery, picasa

Slideshow feature is missing in Gallery for Picasa Web Album after ICS 4.0.4 Update in my Samsung Tab GT-P7310. I was able to run slideshow of Picasa Web Album in Gallery earlier with HC 3.2. This is the same issue even in SIII with stock ICS 4.0.4

I have synced all the Google Account including Picasa Web Albums. I am able to view all the picasa web album pictures in Gallery but not able to slideshow the pictures. Picasa button is in place of slideshow button. However Slideshow is working for Downloads, Camera, Screen Capture Pictures but not for Picasa Web Almums.

Please suggest how to fix or to make it work. Thanks.